# How to change default MSMQ Time-To-Reach-Queue time?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, msmq

We have a problem with Time-To-Reach-Queue being too long in Microsoft Message Queuing on some servers running Windows Server 2008 R2 .

How can we change the default time on the servers from 4 days to a lower value?

(Copy of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957867/how-to-change-default-msmq-time-to-reach-queue-time)

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about servers that belong to a domain AND have MSMQ installed in AD-integrated mode, a default setting for "MaxTimeToReachQueue" can be changed in the "sites and services" MMC snapin. Expand the services folder, right click the "msmqServices" object and set the value on the "general" tab.

**[Set the default lifetime for messages](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738992%28WS.10%29.aspx)**

Any workgroup-mode installations of MSMQ need to specify the value in the code when sending a message.